# Confused on a set inclusion in C* algebras by Murphy

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Im stuck on the following part of this theorem:

The closed vector subspaces of $L^2(T)$ invariant for the bilateral shift $v=M_{z}$ (for $z: T \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ the inclusion map) are precisely the Weiner and Beurling spaces.  If $K$ is a closed invariant subspace for $v$, then:

1. $v(K)=K$ if and only if $K$ is Weiner.
2. $v(K)=K$ if and only if $K$ is Beurling.

Proof: (proving 2)) Suppose that $v(K) \subset K$ properly.  Then since $v(K)$ is closed, there exists a unit $\varphi \in K$ such that $\varphi \in v(K)^{\perp}$.  Since $v^n(\varphi) \in v(K)$ for all $n>0$, it follows that: $$0 = \langle v^n(\varphi), \varphi\rangle = \int_{T} z^n|\varphi(z)|^2 \: d\lambda(z).$$  Since $T$ (the unit circle) is a finite measure space, $L^1(T) \subset L^2(T)$, it follows from above that $|\varphi|^2 \in H^1$, implying that $|\varphi|^2 = \alpha$ almost everywhere.  However $||\varphi||_2=1$, it follows that $\alpha=1$.  Hence, $\varphi \in L^{\infty}(T)$ is a unitary, and clearly $\varphi H^2 \subset K$...

Question:  The text tells me this inclusion is clear, but I don't see it.  Why is $\varphi H^2 \subset K$?  I was trying to show that $\varphi f \in v(K)$ by showing that $$\langle \varphi f,g\rangle = 0 \: \: \forall g \in v(K)^{\perp}, \: f \in H^2$$ but I wasn't able to make any progress.  Any suggestions wiuld be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $e_n=z^n$, for $n\geq0$, is the standard basis for $H^2$, then
$$
\varphi e_n = v^n(\varphi) \in K.
$$